# UIFont monospaced digits + small caps

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uifont, uifontdescriptor

I'm trying to create a [`UIFont`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont) with the following attributes:

- Upper Case Small Caps
- Lower Case Small Caps
- Monospaced Digits

I'm using the system font ([`San Francisco`](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/)), which does supports all theses features.
As far as I know, the only way to do it is to use multiple [`UIFontDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontdescriptor).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
extension UIFont {

    var withSmallCaps: UIFont {
        let upperCaseFeature = [
            UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier : kUpperCaseType,
            UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.typeIdentifier : kUpperCaseSmallCapsSelector
        ]
        let lowerCaseFeature = [
            UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier : kLowerCaseType,
            UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.typeIdentifier : kLowerCaseSmallCapsSelector
        ]
        let features = [upperCaseFeature, lowerCaseFeature]
        let smallCapsDescriptor = self.fontDescriptor.addingAttributes([UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.featureSettings : features])

        return UIFont(descriptor: smallCapsDescriptor, size: pointSize)
    }

    var withMonospacedDigits: UIFont {
        let monospacedDigitsFeature = [
            UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier : kNumberSpacingType,
            UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.typeIdentifier : kMonospacedNumbersSelector
        ]
        let monospacedDigitsDescriptor = self.fontDescriptor.addingAttributes([UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.featureSettings : [monospacedDigitsFeature]])

        return UIFont(descriptor: monospacedDigitsDescriptor, size: pointSize)
    }
}
```

I should be able to obtain a font with all the characteristics mentioned earlier with this line of code:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular).withSmallCaps.withMonospacedDigits
// OR
let font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular).withSmallCaps
```

But for some reasons, it does not work. I can't get the font to have monospaced digits while having small caps at the same time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Probably nothing, except maybe assuming that both features exist within the same variant for that font.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM09/AppendixF.html) document for more details.
I would suggest using attributed strings with small caps for all glyphs but numbers, and another font for monospaced digits. here is some sample code:

```
let monoSpacedDigits = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .medium).withMonospacedDigits
let smallCaps = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular).withSmallCaps



let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: """
H3ll0 7here
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
4444444444
5555555555
6666666666
7777777777
8888888888
9999999999
0000000000
""", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : smallCaps])

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9]")
    let range = NSRange(0..<attributedString.string.utf16.count)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: attributedString.string, range: range)
    for match in matches.reversed() {
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: monoSpacedDigits, range: match.range)
    }
} catch {
    // Do error processing here...
    print(error)
}

myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

I've used a size of 13 and a medium weight to make the monospaced digits look as similar as possible to the small caps.

Comment: `San Francisco` supports both monospaced digits & small caps attributes. That's why I'm using `UIFont.systemFont()`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I figured out why it does not work thanks to the [reference document](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM09/AppendixF.html#Type6) linked by [@Carpsen90](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51883886/2370723).</s>

It seems like the `Number Spacing` feature is **exclusive**.

As stated in the document:

> Features are classified as "exclusive" and "nonexclusive." This indicates whether several different selectors within a given feature type may be selected at once. Thus, it is possible to have both common and rare ligatures turned on, whereas it is impossible to display a given fraction as simultaneously vertical and diagonal.

So **having both monospaced digits + small caps features at the same time is impossible.**

---

### EDIT:

I misread the document. Selectors of that feature are exclusive. But not the whole feature. So it should be possible.

Comment: Yes Number Spacing being exclusive means that `kMonospacedNumbersSelector`, `kProportionalNumbersSelector `, `kThirdWidthNumbersSelector` and `kQuarterWidthNumbersSelector` are exclusive.

Comment: Absolutely! So I still think we should be able to create a font with the requested features.

Comment: In theory, yes. Maybe it's a bug. I've only managed to have small caps, but not monospaced digits with the latest San Francisco family.

Comment: You may be right. I will open a radar and post any relevant updates here.